# number of ways to label in a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a 6 vertices complete graph, Say it G. It is labeled, Now I need to find all distinct 4 vertices cycles. So for first step there are 6C4 ways to select 4 length cycles , but as it is labeled I need to consider labeling also , stuck here. What are no. of ways in which 4 length cycle can be labelled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Selecting the vertices (6C4) doesn't specify the cycle.  You could have $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4$ or $1 \to 3 \to 2 \to 4$  The easy way is just to pick the four vertices in order, because any series of four makes a cycle-how many ways can you do that?  Then recognize that the same cycle can be picked in a number (what number?) of ways.

Comment: :) :) is it 4!??

Comment: For the last question, or for the final answer?

Comment: for the last Ques, final ans would be 6C4 * 4!, is it correct?

Comment: No.  You are choosing four vertices, then putting them in order.  But you have counted the same cycle more than once.  You have $1\to 2 \to 3 \to 4$ and $2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 1$ both counted.